# "On" the campus or "In" the campus? What's the grammatically correct way to say this?

Tags: american-english

This college has multiple campuses: Houston campus, Austin campus, and Dallas campus.

Which sentence is grammatically correct and the proper way to say in English language (American English particularly)?

1. I will be attending the orientation in the Austin campus.
2. I will be attending the orientation on the Austin campus.
3. I will be attending the orientation in Austin campus.
4. I will be attending the orientation on Austin campus.

Or something else?

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in the same post!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You're not asking about college campuses; you're asking about the definite article *the* and prepositions to use with places -- and *at* might also be a possibility. We do have questions about [articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-article) and questions about [prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions). Please do search those and then reformulate your question to ask about what you really want to know.

Comment: I choose "on the Austin campus" or even "at the Austin campus".

Comment: The other question: use of the definite article hereabouts is a grey area†. Go with the flow. There are far more examples of anarthrous 'Austin Campus' than 'the Austin Campus' on the internet. †Famously, the leading British football club is still quite often called 'the Arsenal' as a sign of familiarity.

Comment: *at the Austin campus*